# Derive, infer, deduct and deduce

Tags: difference

"Derive", "infer", "deduct" and "deduce" do have similar meanings.

However, to infer is to make an educated guess, while to deduce is to conclude after a more prolonged analysis of relevant factors.

How about "derive" and "deduce"?

Is "derive" the same as "infer"?

Comment: Did you look them up in a dictionary? What did it say? What exactly did you not understand?

Comment: I saw that all those four words had the following meaning in the dictionary: "reason by deduction; establish by deduction", which made me wonder how "derive" and "deduct" would be used instead of infer and deduce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Infer" is usually used to describe a thought process that makes you believe something based on some evidence, even though that belief can not logically be concluded for certain from that evidence. You could say it was an "educated guess".

"Deduce" means to apply logic to a set of known facts and come to a solid conclusion based on those facts. If the facts are true, the conclusion must also be true because of logic.

"Derive" is mostly used in math or other technical situations. It is also an application of logic to start with one set of facts and systematically reshape them into a different form, equally true. I haven't heard people use the word "derive" in casual conversation though, except with a meaning unrelated to this subject/question. (E.g.: "Vanilla extract is derived from a tropical orchid.") I don't think "derive" would normally be applicable when discussing everyday thought processes.

"Deduct" is commonly used to mean "to subtract". It doesn't normally fit into the group of words you are asking about. Even though the **nouns** derived from the two words "deduce" and "deduct" are the same (namely "deduction"), the verbs themselves don't mean the same thing at all, at least in the dictionaries I checked.

Comment: Wow, what a detailed explanation. It is very helpful!